# DELETE-Queries are taking too much time

Tags: php, mysql, query-optimization, mariadb

I have a MariaDB-tabel `subject_message_new` in a Galera-cluster(3 servers) that registers that users has read a message. We have `31000` users and millions of messages, so the table is very large (now up to 1.5 million records). If a message is updated, all the read-entrys with the `$id_message` must be deleted.

Users can also copy a message to another subject so the message (`$id_message`) refers to the original message (`id_message_org`), also `the-read-entry` from that connected original message has to be deleted.

This is my MySQL-table:

```
Kolom   Type    Commentaar
id  bigint(20) Auto nummering    
id_message  int(11)  
id_subject  int(11) NULL     
nr_user int(11)  
datetime    datetime     

Indexen
PRIMARY id
INDEX   nr_user
INDEX   id_message
INDEX   id_subject

Foreign keys
id_message  subject_message(id_message) CASCADE CASCADE
nr_user users(nr_user)  CASCADE CASCADE
id_subject  subject(id_subject) CASCADE CASCADE
```

I have a PHP-function that is called after a change in the message

```
function message_new($id_message,$id_subject){
 global $conn;
 mysqli_query($conn,"DELETE FROM subject_message_new WHERE (id_message='$id_message' AND id_subject='$id_subject') OR id_message IN(SELECT id_message FROM subject_message WHERE id_message_org='$id_message')");
}
```

If i split the subbquery into `2 x DELETE`-queries it takes `2 x 6-12` seconds...

This function (query) takes too long up to 6-12 seconds in production.
Can someone give me advise how to adjust this? Or make it work better?

Comment: OR and IN are very expensive

Comment: Have a look at `EXPLAIN DELETE ...` (see http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/explain.html ). This should tell you where the slow part is

Comment: Your issue lies in your subselect. You have to either find a way to omit it or optimize it.Firstly you need to make sure that "subject_message.id_message" is indexed.Then seperate them just for clarity. Execute everything before the "OR" and then everything after it.
Then i would focus on optimizing my subselect (Query after the "OR"). Try bringing less records , adding indexes , etc. It is true that OR and IN are expensive but not forbidden , you just do not have the luxury to throw whatever you want in your query , you need to actually "think thoroughly about it and optimize it.

Comment: Hint: DELETE queries can also be attacked with SQL injections the so called time based SQL injections (by misusing MySQL's SLEEP() function)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with that subquery in your delete method.Splitting the single statement into two queries will obviously improve performance.

DELETE FROM subject_message_new WHERE id_message='$id_message' AND id_subject='$id_subject';

DELETE from subject_message_new smn INNER JOIN subject_message sm on smn.id_message = sm.id_message_org;

> NOTE: We should try to prefer JOIN over subqueries while performing **Select, Update or Delete operations**

Then add index in id_message and id_subject column in subject_message_new table. And add index for column id_message_org in subject_message. This should definitely do the trick.

Comment: Thank you for your responding!
Splitting the queries into two DELETE_queries is not helping as I wrote, It will take twice as long, so the subquery is not the problemen, the DELETE-query is the problem. I understand the JOIN has a better performance.  You wrote I have to add several indexes, but the columns are already indexed, also the id_message_org.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe rewriting a query using multi-table `UPDATE/DELETE` syntax will help,
 it will be something like this:

```
DELETE  subject_message_new.* FROM subject_message_new
    LEFT JOIN subject_message
    ON (subject_message_new.id_message = subject_message.id_message)
    WHERE (subject_message_new.id_message='$id_message'
    AND subject_message_new.id_subject='$id_subject')
    OR  id_message.id_message_org='$id_message';
```